# Hover over menu for website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for a way of creating (or piggy-backing off an existing solution) a menu bar that shows a selection of options when hovered over. It's kind of hard to describe so here is a screenshot that shows what I'm after:

[image]

The only thing that I need to be different is the colour scheme of the drop-down menu. I assume this should be fairly easy to change though (please advise anyway).

I have tried googling for this, however I'm not sure I'm searching for the right thing since I'm not aware of the technical terms associated with web design.

Please can someone help me out?

Comment: could you also show your markup and what you have already tried?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/177538). Do something first, then ask help.

Comment: I have tried googling several times however I don't know the right terms to search for. I suspect that I will need to make use of some form of javascript code, however I am stuck at this point and have been for some time. I don't expect people to do research for me at all, I'm just asking for a push in the right direction. Apologies if it came across badly.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the source of the example you posted?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not going to reverse engineer that site for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131866/143302)

Comment: You are looking for css or javascript hover menu. Search for hover menus and you will find tons of tutorials. Please try to research a bit since it'll help you in long run.

Answer (score 0):

you don't even need javascript, you can create pure css dropdowns.
If you feel lazy, try this link:
[purecssmenu.com](http://purecssmenu.com/)

J